# Is there a way to know which shortcode is the last shortcode in a post/page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to know number of shortcodes used in a post/or page and if it's the **last** shortcode on a post/page

```
public function generate_pdf( $attrs ) 
{
    static $i=0;
    $i++;
    echo '<h2>I=</h2>';
    var_dump ( $i );
}

public function __construct() 
{
    add_shortcode( 'pdfcrowd_generate', array($this, 'generate_pdf') );
}
```

If I do something like above and put two shortcodes called `pdfcrowd_generate` in post/page, the number of shortcodes would be displayed:

```
I=
int 1
I=
int 2
```

but is there a way to know what number equals the last shortcode on the post/page?

`get_countshortcodes_onpage()`  - displays 2

If I put 4 shortcodes on the post/page I would want:
`get_countshortcodes_onpage()`  - displays 4

etc etc

**`UPDATE`**
I want to get number of shortcodes to able to remove a file after all shortcodes has been executed.

If comparision to code above I would like to add something like this:

```
public function generate_pdf( $attrs ) 
{
    static $i=0;
    $i++;
    if ( $i === $this->totalcount_shortcodes ) {
     //remove file here
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried modifying the add_shortcodes function to increment a private variable that can be retrieved later?

Comment: You mean modifying `add_shortcode`? That would be bad practice and discouraged.

Comment: There is no method that you can call to see what the amount of shortcodes is, but you could use the global array `$shortcode_tags` which is where you shortcode gets pushed to. So `count($shortcode_tags);` might give you what you want.

Comment: @happymacarts - can you eloberate? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Can't you just override the `add_shortcode`-function/class in your own functions-file?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie - I'm not sure how you mean?

Comment: @putvande - that does not work I'm afraid. I'm using this in admin dashboard in conjunction with ACF and I get 30 shortcodes used instead of the expected 2.

Comment: Seriously? You use @bestprogrammerintheworld as a nick, and you don't know how to override specific functions in WP? Read up, then. Short version: you create your own version of the function, where you save or add usage of specific shortcodes.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie - I know what overriding is of course, but I don't figure how that would help? If you know a solution, please tell me in an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are filters called when shortcodes are executed, so I guess you could add a filter to one of those and increment a global variable everything your filter gets called...

- [pre_do_shortcode_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_do_shortcode_tag/)
- [do_shortcode_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_shortcode_tag/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this, but unfortunately it did not help me ):

Comment: Hmmm... Sorry to hear that. Why did it not? Do you need more help with the implementation?

Comment: Im not sure how to use it in this context

Comment: Oh I see, sorry, re-read the original question. You won't be able to know when the *last* shortcode executes, because you can't know beforehand how many *will* execute. Why do you need this, though?

Comment: Ok - but then why go through a shortcode? Couldn't you just add an action at the end of the loading process (wp_footer or shutdown) and remove your file there?

Comment: Actually neither of these worked, BUT you really got me thinking and I put unlink in hook updated_post_meta instead, because then ALL data is saved to post. Instead of removing file each time I only remove it when data has been updated. So obvious when you think about it. Thanks a LOT!